# How can I use google API for youtube API to study youtube activity of a set of registered users

Tags: youtube-api, social-media

The Google API allows you to retrieve YouTube analytics for content posted by you. I need to understand my registered users' behavior on social media like YouTube. Understand what videos they liked/viewed, what comments they made etc.

I tried using Google API but I can only retrieve YouTube analytics for videos I have posted on you tube

Comment: Where's the documentation that says this is possible? To access analytics data for another user's YouTube channel, that user would need to grant you access to their channel through YouTube's permissions system.